# Creating a perfect scalable div (jsFiddle)

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on designing my website, and I would like to be able to resize/zoom the webpage without messing up the flow of the elements of the website. I am aware that the correct use of % signs solves most of the flow problem, and it seems like it does with everything except text. If I have a simple menu like in the jsfiddle below. The width of the menu div lets say is %30. I would like the text in the menu container to scale to size without wrapping around or entering a new line, which I cant seem to avoid. The same problem remains in the paragraph below. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Scalable</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height:800px; border:1px solid green; width:900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; " >
    <img src="http://files.prof-web-diego.webnode.pt/200000028-04da905d3d/Oxford_Silhouette_Web_Banner.jpg" style="width:50%; height:auto;"/>
    <div style="float:right; width:30%;  border:2px solid blue; font-size:11px;">
        <a href="#">Home<a> |
        <a href="#">Store<a> |
        <a href="#">Contact<a> |
        <a href="#">About<a> |
        <a href="#">Pictures<a> |
        <a href="#">Entertainment<a> |
    </div>

    <div style="border:1px solid #ddd; width:65%;">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula velit in lectus dapibus porta. Sed pulvinar ultrices ipsum vitae gravida. Vestibulum at metus dolor. Nunc pulvinar nisl nec libero sodales faucibus. Quisque tincidunt risus vitae risus tempor viverra. Vestibulum interdum eros in tellus blandit vulputate. Suspendisse eget ante purus, sit amet semper purus. Nam lacinia magna a mi euismod sit amet rhoncus dolor congue. Mauris pharetra laoreet accumsan. Ut quis velit ac nisl rutrum varius nec nec orci.

Vestibulum quis tellus neque, a scelerisque est. In varius ante eget purus fringilla in aliquet massa convallis. Vestibulum in scelerisque ligula. Nulla a neque nibh. Maecenas tristique, odio nec scelerisque tincidunt, sem orci tempus nulla, eu tincidunt dolor sapien ut lorem. Donec aliquet, eros nec blandit adipiscing, leo est malesuada nulla, vel adipiscing sem risus quis ante. Proin rutrum ultrices dolor, quis auctor sem feugiat sit amet. Morbi in tellus nisl, et iaculis turpis. Cras ligula velit, pharetra vitae imperdiet nec, commodo quis erat. Aenean iaculis nunc nec nunc dignissim aliquam. In venenatis, orci vitae pretium elementum, lorem lorem sagittis est, a consectetur est lacus accumsan elit. Vestibulum iaculis hendrerit elit, nec vulputate nunc ornare sit amet. Fusce nisi risus, auctor vitae pellentesque ut, pulvinar nec nisi. Aenean nec nunc augue, non imperdiet arcu. Integer interdum orci non diam tristique ut tristique risus adipiscing. Vestibulum tellus orci, lobortis vel sollicitudin vel, gravida sed dui.

Vestibulum eu dui ni
    </p>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6UyYa/

Comment: you want to implore the use of [Media Queries](http://mediaqueri.es/ "I am just a site of examples")

Comment: [Here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) is also an article explaining what and how to use Responsive Design. I have no idea what @RGB is on about with the SVG? Maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: Yeah SVG is not what i'm looking for, I appreciate the response though.

Comment: Just came across something, Would using em as opposed px accomplish my goal and if so can anyone provide a very simple working example?

Comment: em is relative to the parent. only real diff between that and px. em would be not unlike using %.. you need media-queries to produce a real responsive design, if you want control over sizing past the initial page view... or maybe i'm just really not understanding your question.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is, if a div is a 30% rectangle that contains some text. The text takes up approx. 80% of the div. If a try and resize the site, I would like the text size to stay the same relative to the rectangle div. So no matter how you resize it the text will take up 80% of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches you can take:

1. Use the viewport meta tag to scale the page to the width of the
   device (to the extent that browsers support that)
2. Responsive Design: Use a series of CSS media queries to adapt the content based on the size of the device.

Two versions of Responsive Design:

1. Change the layout of the page (number of columns and how the content flows on the page) based on the size of the device, and optionally scale some of the content. A good example of this is [The Boston Globe](http://www.bostonglobe.com/).
2. Leave the layout unchanged and uniformly scale all of the content. @rlemon mentioned a good [link](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) for this. I learned it by reading Ethan Marcotte's ebook [Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) (unfortunately the ebook isn't free). This approach is relatively difficult and it limits your options.

In both versions of Responsive Design, changes to the content are triggered entirely by CSS media queries (rather than by JavaScript). And the HTML doesn't change. Only the styling of the HTML changes.

The first type of Responsive Design appears to be used much more widely than the second type.

---

For the second type of Responsive Design listed above, a series of media queries for different device sizes sets the base font-size for the body tag in %, and all size units for the content are specified in em or % instead of px (with absolutely no use of px for the content itself). All content is scaled based on whichever media query is used.

Additionally, in the second type of Responsive Design, there's little or no use of background images (at least, in my experience). img tags are used for almost all images, with a special trick for proportionally scaling the img tags via CSS. The following code proportionally scales an image to the full width of its parent container:

```
<img class="my-image" src="image.png"/>   <!-- No width or height attribute -->

.my-image {max-width:100%; width:100%;}
```